# Is it possible to call an initialization method when singleton is created?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is it possible to automatically call an initialization method when a singleton is created?
I am thinking Unity might have some kind of way of doing this.

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService >(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
Container.Resolve<IMyService>().Initialize();
```

Where the service looks like this:

```
class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public void Initialize() 
    {
    }
}
```

Which is not ideal. 
I wish I could avoid calling `Container.Resolve<IMyService>()` which only creates the object just so I can call `Initialize()` on it. And since this is called at app creation time, it hurts app start time.

Comment: You can call Initialize method in Private Constructor...

Comment: Thank you. You're right, that can work. But I realize I have a different issue and might be forced to actually call Initialize at the app startup. This singleton service needs to subscribe to an event generated by another singleton service. I can't see other way other than calling `Initialize` at the startup, which unfortunately will end up creating both of the services (the subscriber gets the publisher instance in c-tor by DI, and subscribes to the event)

Comment: Basically what `Initialize` is doing is it subscribes the service to another service (publisher) event. That's why I need it as early as possible.

Comment: We already have the right tool for this, it's the constructors job to set up the instance. If it needs a dependency on another service, take it as a constructor parameter, this should enforce the right construction order of the two services. It should also postpone the actual initialization until you actually end up constructing the instances.

Answer (score 3):

Although not really in the spirit of Dependency Injection, it is also possible to create your dependency object manually, run any post creation initialization steps on it, and then register the 'usable' object in the container with [RegisterInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650500.aspx).

Since you say `MyService` is a singleton, you can register just the one instance:

```
 var myService = new MyService(<ctor parameters go here>);
 myService.Initialize();
 Container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(myService);
```

If `MyService` itself has complex constructor dependencies that you would like resolved, you could use Unity as a service locator during bootstrap, i.e.

```
 // NB : Resolve the concrete type, not the interface
 var myService = Container.Resolve<MyService>();
 // 'Fix' the instance.
 myService.Initialize();
 // Register via Interface
 Container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(myService);
```

In the more general case (i.e. where a single `MyService` instance cannot be shared), you would need to register a factory, so that the `Initialize` method can be called on each new instance:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyService>(new InjectionFactory(c =>
{
    var transient = c.Resolve<MyService>();
    transient.Initialize();
    return transient;
}));
```

However, as per @Sandy's comment, something seems amiss with the design of class `MyService`, in that after creating the object (with it's constructor having been called), that the object is still not in a state where it can be used until 'Initialize' has been called (i.e. this smells a bit like the object has an assumed 'lifecycle' to it)

Comment: Thank you. To clear it up what I am actually doing, could you please see my answer to Sandy above.

Comment: Ouch - coupling two singletons via an event sounds a bit dirty, but in theory, the same approach should suffice - since both publisher and subscriber are singletons, you can just resolve both concrete instances, and then wire up the event handler (you're basically just mutating the single instance in-place, so you don't need to reregister either instance after the handler is added)

Comment: Newer versions of Unity have deprecated the InjectionFactory in favour of the simpler syntax container.RegisterFactory<IMyService>(c => ...)